# How to read a PDF file from web and store it in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, file-io, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I have PDF files on some server

```
$path = 'http://someserver/somepath/someFile.pdf'
```

I would like to save these files in my Server

```
$file_name = 'someFile.pdf';
$file_handler = fopen('/' . DS . $file_name, 'w');
$PDF_CONTENTS = file_get_contents($path);
file_put_contents($file_handler, $PDF_CONTENTS);
fclose($file_handler);
```

It is creating `someFile.pdf` but no contents.

Comment: a) check the return value of file_get_contents, i.e. $PDF_CONTENTS b)  `file_put_contents ( string $filename` not  `file_put_contents ( resource $filehandle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of using `fopen`.
Try

```
 $storeLocation = '/pdf/mypdf.pdf';
 $PDF_CONTENTS = file_get_contents($path);
 file_put_contents($storeLocation, $PDF_CONTENTS);
```